# Would my question be better off on philosophy.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, specific-question

I think it kind of straddles the lines between the two stackexchange sites, should it be moved?

[As a white cis-gender male you can't comment on [woke cause]?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/60623/as-a-white-cis-gender-male-you-cant-comment-on-woke-cause)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This question is definitely off-topic here on Politics Stack Exchange.

The [help center article about what's on-topic on politics stack exchange](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says:

> Politics Stack Exchange is for objective questions about governments, policies and political processes.

Is it a question about governments or policies? No, it's not the government which tells you to not state an opinion on certain matters. Private people claim that.

Is it a question about political processes? Not as long as certain political decision makers are forbidden from getting involved in the political process when it's about certain sociopolitical matters. And so far I am not aware of any such rules.

Is it even an objective question? No, it's a subjective question. Different people have different ideas about who has the moral authority to state their opinions on which matter. This makes this a subjective matter.

So no, this question is not in scope on this website.

Is this question on-topic on Philosophy Stack Exchange, though? We can not answer this here, because we don't have the authority to speak on behalf of other communities of the Stack Exchange network. You have to ask about that on the
[Philosophy Stack Exchange meta-site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com). Although maybe you can answer this yourself by reading the help article about [what's on topic on philosophy SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thank you, I agree it is off-topic on this site then. I did look at https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, but it's not clear to me that it would be welcome there either, as you say I'd have to ask them.

Answer (score 0):

Although I voted to close this q, I think the first part of Phipp's answer is too narrow.

Question are also on-topic if the idea is clearly part of a political ideology, not just a process or law. E.g. we had a lot of "how do libertarians respond to situation/issue X" here. And also q like "what are arguments for/against position X", where X is a well-known contentious issue in political discourse/ideology. See e.g. [this meta-answer](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4642/18373) from another mod on that issue.

But for your q it's not terribly clear that's the case. Someone's random idiosyncratic idea (e.g. about acceptable speech), even if "political", expressed in a conversation doesn't immediately qualify. If this q was written in a less ranty manner (about a personal experience) and instead quoted something respectable to show that this is a reasonably widespread idea in political discourse (but please no caricatures or "straw men" made by someone to ridicule someone else) then it may be ok to ask e.g. what arguments are for it or what counterarguments are against it. Speaking of which, the q itself contained a long diatribe against the position, which made it read like a "push" question. (The title itself, with the "woke cause" term made it read like a headline from a right-wing tabloid.)